# Unable to tunnel and decrypt thru Fiddler Proxy

Tags: ssl, encryption, fiddler

I'm using Fiddler Proxy to decrypt HTTPS traffic for a specific application, the problem I'm facing is the application seem to be using the internal browser to render part of the information and it seems when rendering to browser Fiddler is unable to tunnel even tho it's hitting the same hostname.. I've capture a successful and an unsuccessful connection but I'm not expert on this so hopping someone can give a hand and tell me if it's something that can be resolved somehow.  To give complete info, I'm using jailbroken iPhone XR with SSLKillSwitch to bypass pinning certificate errors, it works for regular options in the App but when I get to the section where it uses the internal webkit browser then the tunnel closes the connections.

**Here is a successful tunnel stablished:**

```
CONNECT api.xxxxxxxxx.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.xxxxxxxx.com
User-Agent: Driver/1003.95.3.17728954 CFNetwork/1240.0.4 Darwin/20.6.0
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 53 36 A3 4D 40 7F 06 DC 59 EF 0D F2 67 BF 69 13 90 B3 40 A7 30 A1 14 54 E8 D0 ED 0D 99 78 66 05
"Time": 4/11/2011 1:11:47 PM
SessionID: 67 37 00 00 89 55 CA 97 B4 ED 1E 51 D3 52 84 D9 C0 95 92 E8 3E AA 22 59 39 ED EE 34 40 D5 26 96
Extensions: 
    grease (0xaaaa) empty
    server_name api.xxxxxxxx.com
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
    supported_groups    grease [0xfafa], x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18], secp521r1 [0x19]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    ALPN        http/1.1
    status_request  OCSP - Implicit Responder
    signature_algs  ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha1
    SignedCertTimestamp (RFC6962)   empty
    key_share   00 29 FA FA 00 01 00 00 1D 00 20 63 5F C7 E5 45 CB 0C 1B 17 34 69 DF B4 F5 98 0C 91 23 A5 D8 C0 17 C9 8D CC 70 B8 23 C7 79 67 1A
    psk_key_exchange_modes  01 01
    supported_versions  grease [0x2a2a], Tls1.3, Tls1.2
    grease (0xcaca) 00
    padding     214 null bytes
Ciphers: 
    [BABA]  Unrecognized cipher - See https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
    [1301]  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [1302]  TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [1303]  TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [CCA9]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [C030]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [CCA8]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION



HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 08:53:48.980
Connection: close

Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list.

Secure Protocol: Tls12
Cipher: Aes128 128bits
Hash Algorithm: Sha256 ?bits
Key Exchange: ECDHE_RSA (0xae06) 255bits

== Server Certificate ==========
[Subject]
  CN=*.xxxxxx.com, O="Xxxxxx, Inc.", L=San Francisco, S=California, C=US

[Issuer]
  CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US

[Serial Number]
  0E5C9FB26125F869BF32DEFE4B26822E

[Not Before]
  6/13/2022 8:00:00 PM

[Not After]
  7/15/2023 7:59:59 PM

[Thumbprint]
  4F91631510EC84B84A195014E335B1C6748318AF

[SubjectAltNames]
*.xxxxxx.com, xxxxx.com, *.xxxxx.net, xxxxx.net, *.xxxxx.me, xxxxx.me, *.xxxxx.ca, xxxxx.ca, *.xxxxxxxxx.com, xxxxxxxx.com
```

**And tunnel unsuccessful:**

```
CONNECT api.xxxxxx.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.xxxxxxx.com
User-Agent: com.apple.WebKit.Networking/8611.4.1.0.3 CFNetwork/1240.0.4 Darwin/20.6.0
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: E2 EF 8D 53 08 4F D9 3E 23 DB BA 45 40 A6 A2 ED 6E 23 3B 84 C6 00 98 75 9F 03 5C 95 6C 7E 6B 1E
"Time": 6/3/2014 11:55:14 AM
SessionID: CA 79 37 63 83 57 8B E1 86 24 8F F0 18 FA A9 27 83 52 1E 5B BD 39 27 86 94 CB 54 68 7D 7B FD 3E
Extensions: 
    grease (0x1a1a) empty
    server_name api.xxxxxx.com
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
    supported_groups    grease [0xcaca], x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18], secp521r1 [0x19]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    ALPN        h2, http/1.1
    status_request  OCSP - Implicit Responder
    signature_algs  ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha1
    SignedCertTimestamp (RFC6962)   empty
    key_share   00 29 CA CA 00 01 00 00 1D 00 20 2C 81 5B 83 4E A9 2F E0 17 99 47 E1 51 C3 88 5E 6C 65 3C F6 FF FD DE BD B6 4F 3F 38 73 DB 1F 15
    psk_key_exchange_modes  01 01
    supported_versions  grease [0xdada], Tls1.3, Tls1.2
    grease (0x8a8a) 00
    padding     211 null bytes
Ciphers: 
    [EAEA]  Unrecognized cipher - See https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
    [1301]  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [1302]  TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [1303]  TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [CCA9]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [C030]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [CCA8]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION



HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 08:53:46.605
Connection: close
```

Edited to add the error I get in Fiddler Log:

```
08:53:46:7774 !SecureClientPipeDirect failed: System.IO.IOException Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream. for pipe (CN=*.xxxxxxx.com, O=DO_NOT_TRUST, OU=Created by http://www.fiddler2.com)
```

Notice I've edited the actual hostname and developer info on purpose for privacy but left everything else untouched.. you can see different user-agent showing when it's using the browser and failing and when it's not.

Hope someone can give some clues on how to address.  By using a different proxy (Mockttp) this works fine so I'm hoping Fiddler can also do it since it's more user friendly for my purpose.

Edited to clarify that I'm using **SSL Kill Switch 2 (0.14-3+debug)**

Edit2: It turns out my version of SSL Kill Switch 2 was older than latest and some fixes were now in place.  I updated and now there is no certificate errors anymore, however, after the request worked for a couple of times I started getting 403 which initially I thought it was my IP being denied but then testing with Postman I get 200 all the time, I'm only denied when using Fiddler Proxy so still trying to figure out why the difference.  I'm making sure Postman is sending exactly all the same headers and message as the app from the phone.  Comparing a working vs denied from the phone doesn't seem to show any differences either.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question add the link to the SSLKillSwitch  version you use. Is it possible that the connection that fails uses a client certificate and thus is rejected by the server? Another possibility is that the server performs TLS fingerprinting. iPhones can be pretty well fingerprinted and I am sure the fingerprint will be different form a .NET application. Last but not least the server may be TLS 1.3 only (which is not supported by Fiddler classic).

Comment: Thanks @Robert for taking the time.  As suggested I've updated the post to clarify I'm using SSL Kill Switch 2 (0.14-3+debug).  Also want to highlight both tunnels above are to the same hostname (api.xxxx.com), I can give the exact host if it's relevant just wasn't sure if that's again the rules here.  Wouldn't that mean the TLS fingerprinting should be more random rather than always affect the one from the browser? again, I'm not expert so please ignore if what I say really makes no sense :-)

Comment: Some web site use HSTS and thus prevent man-in-the-middle attacks once the certificate hashes has been transmitted (it is a little bit like ssh using trust-on-first-use). Nur sure if SSLKillSwitch will also bypass this. The easiest way would be to delete the app specific web cache or all the app data to make sure all HSTS data are deleted.

Comment: hi @Robert  Some progress but still have issue. You definitely pointed me in the right direction, my phone had killswitch for some years so I delete it and got latest package from GitHub and the cert error is gone.  The requests worked for a couple of times and then I started getting 403.  I compared a working request and the denied one and can't find any differences and same thru Postman works. I'm only being denied when it goes thru Fiddler.  Any suggestions on how I could debug more why I get 403 on Fiddler but 200 in Postman?

Comment: You can try different interception proxies like mitmproxy (Python) or Burp/ZAP (Java). Python and Java has a different TLS fingerprint than .Net

Answer (score -1):

@Robert pointed out it could be an issue with SSL Killswitch rather than Fiddler Proxy. After upgrading to a more recent version I no longer get the tunnel issue <sup><sub>(though now I'm having a different problem which seems to be related to TLS fingerprint which I think I was able to confirm by using different proxy).</sub></sup>